# Can't convert Python byte array to GLib GArray_guchar with NetworkManager/GLib

Tags: python, linux, networking, gtk, glib

I'm using the Python interface to NetworkManager to configure network connections in Linux. I am able to add connections, but am getting an error when setting the hardware (MAC) address of a wired connection. This code illustrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import NetworkManager

s_wired = NetworkManager.SettingWired.new()
addr = '00:32:12:34:56:11'
mac_bytes = NetworkManager.utils_hwaddr_atoba(addr, 1)

s_wired.set_property(NetworkManager.SETTING_WIRED_MAC_ADDRESS, mac_bytes)    
# ^^^ TypeError: could not convert 'b'\x002\x124V\x11'' to 
#     type 'GArray_guchar_' when setting property 'NMSettingWired.mac-address'
```

The NetworkManager API is implemented in C and uses GLib, so as far as I understand the problem here, there is something going on with the type conversion between Python and the GLib or GObject system. Here is some version and type info:

```
>>> NetworkManager._version
'1.0'
>>> mac_bytes.__class__
<class 'bytes'>
```

Since 'mac_bytes' (which is a byte array) is about as close to an array of unsigned chars as I can get, I would think the type conversion system shouldn't have a problem. I'm using GLib and GObject introspection in Python, so I'd prefer a GLib solution over a D-Bus one if possible, but anything that works will help. At this time, I'm unable to upgrade the NetworkManager version (shown above).

Any ideas of how to resolve this error?

API Reference: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/Developers